# Oracle scheduler job sometimes failing, without error message

Tags: oracle, dbms-scheduler

I have created a dbms scheduler job which should write a short string to the alert log of each instance of the 9 databases on our 2-node 11g Oracle RAC cluster, once every 24 hours.

The job action is:

`'dbms_system.ksdwrt(2, to_char(sysdate+1,''rrrr-mm-dd'') || ''_First'');'`

which should write a line like:

2014-08-27_First

The job runs succesfully according to its log, and it does write what it's supposed to, but not always. It's only been scheduled for a few days, so I can't be certain, but it looks as if it will only write to one instance's alert log. Logs on both sides seem to be getting written to, but if it's on one side it's not on the other, so it appears. There is however no indication whatever of any failure in the job itself.

Can anyone shed any light on this behaviour? Thanks.

Comment: I believe that the scheduler would need to choose one instance in which to run the job (instance either specified by the job setup or chosen by Oracle at runtime).  So if you're writing to the alert log using dbms_system.ksdwrt (really for dev testing, I don't think its supported), it will write to that instance's alert log.  I don't have access to a RAC env to test but I believe this is whats happening.  Perhaps you should write to a log table and poll that.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @tbone.

I created 2 new jobs, one for each node, and set instance_id to the appropriate instance number as indicated at  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36526/specify-server-for-dbms-scheduler-job-in-policy-managed-rac and also instance_stickiness to false after a couple of tries, in case the scheduled job was "sticking" to the first instance it had run on.

Nonetheless, the instance 2 job continues resolutely to write to the instance 1 alert log, as does the instance 1 job.

Comment: I would think if you want to specify an instance, you'd want stickiness on (default is TRUE).

Comment: Well, I first manually test-ran the instance-specified jobs with stickiness on (I checked the instance in dba_scheduler_jobs), but sometimes they still ran on the wrong instance. My working hypothesis was that they had already "stuck" themselves to the wrong instance,  overriding the specified instance. After all it’s an "undocumented feature" (: Initial testing manually running the job still wrote to the wrong instance , leaving me none the wiser, the point at which I posted yesterday. When the jobs ran at the scheduled time, they did seem to run on the correct instance. I’ll recheck tomorrow

Comment: You could say documentation by hypothesis :)

Thanks by the way @tbone for your suggestions which are much appreciated. I am aware of the option of outputting the alert logs to external tables, in fact this is already happening for another reason, but those tables contain a week's worth of logs. I have a scripted routine to read just the portion of each log over the last 24 hours (give or take a few minutes) and report on the ORA- errors found. I use the daily stamp to tell the script where to start reading

Comment: This time all 18 jobs wrote to the correct instance log. This corroborates the hypothesis that instance specificity for a dbms_scheduler job, at least using the undocumented DBMS_system.ksdwrt routine, only applies when the job is run at the scheduled time and not when started manually. And it also means my problem is solved. Perhaps the routine is now a little less undocumented

Comment: Great, good to hear it worked out!